# How do I handle SSL certificate error in python and selenium POM framework?

Tags: python, selenium, frameworks, pytest, pageobjects

Im very new to all this, but I've made a hybrid framework (python, selenium, pytest, page object model) for practicing automation with and kind of hit a tough one with SSL certs and how to ignore the certificate error.I'm using the https://expired.badssl.com site to test it with

The code I've found to use is:

```
    options = self.driver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    self.driver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

and I'm just unsure to where it needs to go, if it even is the correct code to use.
This is what is in my conftest.py file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options


@pytest.fixture()
def setup(browser):
    if browser == 'chrome':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver


# have to include --browser (opyion) otherwise will return error
# added else, if no browser is specified, default to chrome


def pytest_addoption(parser):  # this will get the value from the cli/hooks
    parser.addoption("--browser")


@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):  # this will return the browser to the setup method
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")


####### Pytest HTML reports #######

# hook for adding environment info to html report
def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'Hybrid Framework'
    config._metadata['Module Name'] = 'Customers'
    config._metadata['Tester'] = 'Amar'

# hook for delete/modify environment info to html report
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_metadata(metadata):
    metadata.pop("JAVA_HOME", None)
    metadata.pop("Plugins", None)
```

I've created a 'sslcert_page.py' page object class and a 'test_sslcert.py'. I've tried including the code in the test file, so it looks like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from pageObjects.SSLCertificate.sslcert_page import SSLCertHandling
from utilities.readProperties import ReadConfig


class Test_sslcertf:
    baseURL = ReadConfig.getApplicationURL()

    # logger = LogGen.loggen()

    def test_1(self, setup):
        # self.logger.info("************* Test_001_Login *************")
        self.driver = setup
        options = self.driver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        self.driver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        sleep(5)
        self.sslcert = SSLCertHandling
        #self.sslcert.ignoreCert()
```

But it doesn't even load the page when I execute the test in the terminal.

Hope someone with more knowledge around this can help me out. The code is fine when it is done without a page object model set up. thanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get(
    "https://untrusted-root.badssl.com/")
```

you have to use desired capability

Comment: Thanks. I put it into the conftest.py file, in the setup method, just before the if statement for chrome, thats where my driver initialize is for chrome

it loads the webpage now but still doesn't ignore the certificate error :/

Comment: again you have an elee webdriver.webdriver()

Comment: I've put the same under else statement now and its going to the site, thank you !!

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign